# How to allign another 2 textbox in the right side in bootsrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class = "container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class = "container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                     placeholder="Name of Instructor"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                     placeholder="Subject"/>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right">
              <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Heres my code for the 4 textboxes yes i copied your code sorry because im only a beginner.

Here's the image:

[image]

I want to add two more in the right side

**Updated image:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.pull-right` class.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class = "container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class = "container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                     placeholder="Name of Instructor" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                     placeholder="Subject"/>

            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update2**

Use [`col-*-offset`](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp) to "push" the other inputs right.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class = "container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class = "container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                     placeholder="Name of Instructor"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                     placeholder="Name of Instructor"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                     placeholder="Subject"/>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                     placeholder="Subject"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice i it adds two more in the right but its not alligned with the two in the left

Comment: My code is just a **demo**. You shouldn't copy\paste it as is. Just add the class `pull-right` to the **existing** parent of the inputs. If there is no common parent, make one. Can you show me your code, or if your project is a live, send me a link.

Comment: You can edit your question and add a snippet of your code using [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). **But** did you copy\paste my demo. Have you tried to add the class to the parent **without** copy\paste my code?

Comment: I was updated my code. In your situation, remove the code you copied from my answer and just add `pull-right` class to both of the inputs (see my answer)

Comment: I mean, i want to add more two boxes in the right and the 2 boxes in the left will still remain and alligned to the new boxes to the right